# Android Gradle Fallback to Another Build Variant

Tags: android, gradle, build-variant

I have four build variants, A, B, C and D.  For a specific activity I have common code in a base class in the main source sets.  I want to additional functionality such that A & B have the same additionally functionality and C & D have the same functionality which is different from A & B.  I have been able to do this by copy and pasting the extending class in the source sets for A & B and C & D respectively; however, that makes maintenance an issue.  I cannot merge variants A & B or C & D because they do have other important differences.  How do I include the class such that it is only in A and B references it and only C and D references it.  I tried adding java source sets but then it couldn't find any other classes or other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by creating two new directories E & F.  Then I added source sets for A & B to be their current source sets and E and for C & D I added F.

```
sourceSets {
    A {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/A/java', 'src/public/E']
    }
    B {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/B/java', 'src/public/E']
    }
    C {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/C/java', 'src/internal/F']
    }
    D {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/D/java', 'src/internal/F']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#resolve_matching_errors

```
// In the app's build.gradle file.
android {
    flavorDimensions 'tier'
    productFlavors {
        paid {
            dimension 'tier'
            // Because the dependency already includes a "paid" flavor in its
            // "tier" dimension, you don't need to provide a list of fallbacks
            // for the "paid" flavor.
        }
        free {
            dimension 'tier'
            // Specifies a sorted list of fallback flavors that the plugin
            // should try to use when a dependency's matching dimension does
            // not include a "free" flavor. You may specify as many
            // fallbacks as you like, and the plugin selects the first flavor
            // that's available in the dependency's "tier" dimension.
            matchingFallbacks = ['demo', 'trial']
        }
    }
}
```

and more documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/ProductFlavor#matchingfallbacks